# Why is my readable web stream for http incoming message reading random data from system memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made a polyfill class which tries to emulate the behavior of ReadableStreamDefaultReader web `API`. The purpose was sharing code that processes downloaded text files between browser and `NodeJS`.

Now I did notice sometimes the number of lines didn't quite add up. I tried to find the minimal case where this happens, and I now see that my reader is reading from internal NodeJS memory (or worse, system). I am not sure why. The problem is almost certainly in the`NodeReadableStreamReader` class, but I am posting the entire example that you can run. It only requires `express` for hosting the "file" that the test is fetching.

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";

/**
* Just a slim wrapper to await response headers to be read
* @param {string} url
* @returns {Promise<http.IncomingMessage>}
*/
function httpStreamPromise(url) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       http.get(url, (result)=>{
           resolve(result);
       })
   });
}

/** @typedef {import("stream").Readable} NodeStreamReadable **/


class NodeReadableStreamReader {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {NodeStreamReadable} readableStream 
     */
    constructor(readableStream) {
        this._stream = readableStream;
    }

    get isReadable() {
        return this._stream.readable && !this._stream.closed;
    }

    async read() {
        if(this.isReadable) {
            /** @type {Buffer} **/
            let data = this._stream.read();
            // if there was no data, await the stream to be readable
            if(!data && this.isReadable) {
                const onReadable = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                    const callbacks = [];
                    const itsMe = this;
                    // this allows removal of the callbacks once either has fired
                    function removeListeners() {
                        for(const cb of callbacks) {
                            itsMe._stream.off(cb[0], cb[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    const readableCb = ()=>{
                        removeListeners();
                        resolve(true);
                    };
                    const closeCb = ()=>{
                        removeListeners();
                        resolve(false);
                    };
                    const errorCb = (e)=>{removeListeners();console.log("Stream error!");reject(e)};
                    callbacks.push(["readable", readableCb], ["close", closeCb], ["error", errorCb]);
                    // must handle all three scenarios
                    this._stream.once("readable", readableCb);
                    this._stream.once("close", closeCb);
                    this._stream.once("error", errorCb);
                });

                const canBeRead = await onReadable;
                if(canBeRead)
                    data = this._stream.read();
            }
            if(data) {
                return {value: new Uint8Array(data.buffer), done:false};
            }
        }

        return {value: null, done: true};
    }
}

const HTTP_PORT = 1*process.env.PORT || 16661;

const app = express()

/** @type {string[]} **/
const lines = [
    'Line 1 ewhbjl khqani pfz zqgqm whlfa uef cgo qzzmapp',
    'Line 2 mlzsacg vclfvf qztwkq wghb iubzmb lyup cnzur kvhb dqnp tgrncv krpbrt vmjts vkl',
    'Line 3 vmqo udvm dqriyn aakqizi dfelzz vnrfr bfahax csh axvvzv cpwoxat aps',
    'Line 4 lfnl hupcxtk xojsyv zdzno vrf ynnod goauegh blpjk tjp oqfw jhymx chngdkb ymuchj',
    'Line 5 kztxq xxn kheqqfk ldhzo oywiqtu xsnnzjg yarwred gfggg tysym aks zlv ugkf',
    'Line 6 agdtvq qwai dsjfwb jydlcl'
  ]

console.log(lines);
app.get(["/test.txt"], (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Sending "+lines.length+" lines");
    for(const line of lines) {
        res.write(line + "\n");
    }
    res.send();
});

const server = app.listen(HTTP_PORT, async (err)=>{
    console.log(`Listening on localhost:${HTTP_PORT}`);

    const req = await httpStreamPromise(`http://localhost:${HTTP_PORT}/test.txt`);
    if(req.statusCode != 200) {
        console.error("Invalid status code: "+req.statusCode);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    const webStream = new NodeReadableStreamReader(req);
    let chunk = {done: false};
    /** @type {Uint8Array[]} **/
    let chunks = [];
    while(!chunk.done) {
        chunk = await webStream.read();
        if(!chunk.done)
            chunks.push(chunk.value);
    }
    const totalLen = chunks.reduce((p, x)=>p+x.byteLength, 0);
    const merged = new Uint8Array(totalLen);
    let off = 0;
    for(const ar of chunks) {
        merged.set(ar, off);
        off += ar.length;
    }
    const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    console.log(utf8Decoder.decode(merged));
    server.close();
});
```

The unwanted data are random and appear both before and after the desired content. I get random JS sourcecode as well as plain nonsense.